# How to check if you've reached the last child of a parent node Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML response which I'd like to parse. And I seem to have it working however I'd like to know, how (in Java code) can I know I've reached the lastChild of the parent node

**XML:**

```
<Data>
    <Lambda>Test</Lambda>
    <Gr>Function</Gr>
    <Approach>Method</Approach>
    <Sentence>
        <Text id="1">You are tall because </Text>
        <Entry id="2">ApplicableConditions</Entry>
        <Text id="3">.</Text>
    </Sentence>
</Data>
```

**Code:**

```
String sentence = new String();
List<String> sentList = new ArrayList<>();
sentence += node.getTextContent();
// If last sibling and no children, then put current sentence into list
if(!node.hasChildNodes() && !node.getLastChild().hasChildNodes()) { 
    sentList.add(sentence);
}
```

For example, when the current node is on Text id=3, how can I check to see this is indeed the last child of the parent node Sentence? This way I can add the constructed sentence into the list and read it later.

This way I will have the following String item in sent list:

> You are tall because ApplicableConditions.

Edit:

```
<Data>
    <Lambda>Test</Lambda>
    <Gr>Function</Gr>
    <Approach>Method</Approach>
    <Sentence>
        <Text id="1">You are tall because </Text>
        <Entry id="2">ApplicableConditions</Entry>
        <Text id="3">.</Text>
    </Sentence>
</Data>

<Data>
    <Lambda>Test2</Lambda>
    <Gr>Fucntion</Gr>
    <Approach>Method</Approach>
    <Sentence>
        <Text id="1">Because you don't have any qualifying dependents and you are outside the eligible age range, </Text>
        <Entry id="2">you don't qualify for this credit.</Text>
        <BulletedList id="3">
            <QuestionEntry id="4">
                <Role>Condition</Role>
            </QuestionEntry>
        </BulletedList>
    </Sentence>
</Data>
```

Notice for this second one, the structure is slightly different...How to take different structure into account. My solution doesn't seem to be working here... since there is no attribute on the last child of the child of Sentence. Perhaps better to use Xpaths?

Comment: What does this have to do with regex?

Comment: It was a stackoverflow recommendation :)

Comment: Do not add tags unless they are relevant to your question.

Comment: You can use regex to parse an xml doc (not recommended though), perhaps there is a way to accomplish my question using regex, not sure since I am asking the question

Comment: Yes, I know regexes. Many people, including me, watch the tag for questions and it's annoying when it's a false alarm.

Comment: Do you think this is a false alarm? If so, I can remove the regex tag

Comment: Yes, because you're not using regexes, nor looking for one.

Comment: I wouldn't say I'm not looking for a regex, I'm looking for a solution to solve my problem which regex could potentially solve. I've added an algorithm tag in it's stead, hopefully someone can help.

Comment: I don't understand how the problem can arise. You should traverse the children of the Sentence node, appending all their text to a string, then append the string to the list. You don't have to decide when you're on the last iteration inside the loop: you can just move the final action outside the loop, whatever it is.

Comment: How do you know you've reached the last child of the parent Sentence? Without checking you've reached the last child, adding the sentence to the list would give you 3 separate string items from id=1, id=2, id=3. Exactly what you said I was doing but it seems algorithmically without that check, the list could contain extraneous items, only the last one being the complete sentence.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to solve for my problem. I locate the last sibling, and then just compare the current Node attribute value with the last node attribute value, if they are the same add the constructed sentence to string List.

**Code:**

```
...
Element ele = (Element) node;
if(ele.getAttribute("id") == getLastChildElement(nNode).getAttribute("id")) {
    sentList.add(sentence);
}

public static Element getLastChildElement(Node parent) {
    // search for node
    Node child = parent.getLastChild();
    while (child != null) {
        if (child.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            return (Element) child;
        }
        child = child.getPreviousSibling();
    }
    return null;
}
```